interaction between covariate and IV in three way repeated ANCOVA
I have conducted a three-way repeaped ANCOVA with a 432 design. There is no main effect. However, I have found an interaction effect between my covariate and one of the IVs. How can I check which levels of IVs were effected by my covariate?

Please explain your research question and also let us know the model details
